# Does warnings add to compile time in swift

Tags: swift, warnings, llvm

May be this question is asked many times for other languages but I want to understand if Swift compile time increases if we have may warnings in code.

Is it that needs to be considered on priority as My code (after swift 3 conversion) have more than 700 warnings (including pods).

Comment: Build time is irrelevant. Your priority should be fixing all warnings. Code that doesn't compile clean is bad code with bugs that will cause you problems.

Comment: Absolutely agree, thats what is planned next to cleanup but was just wondering.